# What is the command line equivalent of PRAM reset?

Tags: startup, mac-pro, nvram

My wired keyboard is starting to flake out and I'm not able to PRAM reset the machine at boot with the <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> sequence. I tried plugging in a Windows keyboard and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Windows key</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd>  + <kbd>R</kbd> , but the Mac doesn't seem to recognize the sequence.

Is there a command line equivalent to the keyboard boot sequence above? I tried `sudo nvram -c` but that didn't seem to do it.

The idea is that I want to set the boot volume to something else, but I'm flying blind on a MacPro3,1 since the video card is a non-EFI PC one so I can't just do the "hold option at boot" trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would setting the boot volume with the *Startup Disk* option or `bless` command be sufficient?

Comment: `bless` does work for setting the startup drive, but that doesn't do the PRAM reset. So yes, I did get my boot drive issue solved but leaving question as-is since I still don't see a command line equivalent to the key sequence above; I did a `sudo nvram -c` as indicated, but it didn't reset the boot drive so they don't appear to be equivalent.